# "Invalid Credentials given" error with valid credential (o-auth-provider)

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I'm following OAuth2 provider tutorial. After setting up everthing correctly, I'm getting this error.

`Invalid Credentials given`

What am I doing wrong with request? I checked my username and password but it's 100% valid.

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=j1357924680" 
-u"TEAfdIRw5cE664Pd4X31wuD7y08er8Suim3SdZsr:dI65CQwo9glm9LN63twmqDSY2DHR9bbPqlSEIwktaOzMfAS7sSFirzCKi9enogNZmyHjqQeIYIqtwKY6RIUC7Lto22s4vDtB0Y7F5unffLdktHXPyPn7j593IAeHfTDp" 
http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

(If you want to see its actual source code) https://github.com/jbaek7023/DRFOAuth2

OAuth2 is very complicating

Comment: Can you test on Postman. maybe?

Comment: Postman shows samething :(